# Stuck at "Client modified--refreshing" on Terminal after Code Refresh

Tags: meteor, client

I installed Meteor (p.s I'm new to app developement) onto my laptop (running Windows 10) and have created an app for which I have downloaded packages for (materialize, accounts-ui and passwords). The problem that I'm facing is that whenever I make changes to the html,css or js files, I get "client-modified" on my terminal, but it never actually refreshes. It's just stuck there in a loop after no matter how many modifications I make. Is this due to the current Meteor version I have installed (1.2.1)?

> => Client modified -- refreshing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me also, yesterday and today, that's how I found this question.
My observations are:

1. check if the app is running and working despite the apparent hang. If it does, try making a simple change in a html or template file and see if the app auto-updates. It did for me, but your mileage may vary.
2. If it gets too annoying, you can always just kill and restart the app. Shouldn't take too long. Check if this improves the situation.
3. If 2. does not help you may try "meteor reset" to clean things up, but ONLY if you just started developing your app and don't care about losing any app data (MongoDB get's wiped along with the rest of the /.meteor/local folder)

Hope the above helps...
Norbert

Comment: Thanks Norbert for the tips! Apparently, there were some packages I had installed that once removed helped to increase the build time and stop the lagging refresh.